# Who renamed a directory?

Tags: files, rename, forensics

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere. How can I know who renamed a directory?

`ls -al` shows only the name of user who created that dirctory.

Comment: "ls -al shows only the name of user who created that dirctory." No. It shows the name of the user who "owns" that directory.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, which unless someone (limited to `root` only on most systems) did a `chown` on the directory, will be the effective uid of  the process that created that directory.

Comment: Sure, usually they're the same, but _they don't have to be_.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is not information that is normally recorded, unless you took special disposition to that effect (like via some audit system).

The service through which the user has renamed the directory (like over FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, samba...) may have logs that can help. You can try and check those logs, the `last`, `lastcomm`, `audit`, authentication logs around the time the folder was renamed.

If you're administrator, you can look at the history file of the shells of the users that had the permissions to rename it (if the directory was renamed from `/A/dir` to `/B/newdir`, it's whoever had write access to both `/A` and `/B` (assuming `/A` didn't have the `t` bit in its permissions and `/A/dir` and `/B` are on the same filesystem)).

Answer (score 5):

You can't. As renaming a directory (or a file) is changing an entry in a (the parent) directory, it must have been someone with write permissions to that directory, but it is not registered anywhere who changes files/directories.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [loggedfs](https://rflament.github.io/loggedfs/).

> Description
>
> LoggedFS is a fuse-based filesystem which can log every operations
>   that happens in it.
>
> How does it work ?
>
> Fuse does almost everything. LoggedFS only sends a message to syslog
>   when called by fuse and then let the real filesystem do the rest of
>   the job.

It is available as deb in Ubuntu. Very funny thing.
However, when you will try to use it on busy server it will eat all your disk space easily.